# Does Qt have cyclic buffer?

Tags: c++, qt

I couldn't find anything similar.
I found that boost library has an implementation, but I'm not sure I want to insert the whole library just for cyclic buffer implementation.

Comment: Since boost is a header only library don't you just need the cyclic buffer related files?

Comment: @NathanOliver On the one hand, the final compiled executable or library will only have generated code related to the cyclic buffer. On the other hand, you need to download the entire boost library (every boost library I've used has plenty of dependencies on other boost libraries)

Answer (score 1):

There are no such types in Qt's public API. If you're willing to use Qt's internals, there are two classes of note:

1. `QRingBuffer`

   Stores bytes and is tailored for I/O buffering. Used by `QSerialPort` etc.

   ```
   QT += core-private  # In the .pro file

   #include <private/qringbuffer_p.h>
   ```

   https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.9/src/corelib/tools/qringbuffer_p.h
2. `QCircularBuffer`

   Stores arbitrary types and is of general use. Provides sensible STL-style API.

   ```
   QT += 3dcore-private  # In the .pro file

   #include <private/qcircularbuffer_p.h>
   ```

   https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/5.9/src/core/resources/qcircularbuffer_p.h

Note: After adding the private modules to the project file, you have to re-run qmake, or ideally delete the build folder. **A mere rebuild of the project won't get the code to compile!**

Comment: these are is only for 5.X.X version? we still use 4.X.X version.

Comment: You can copy them over from Qt 5. They'll work OK. For either one, it's just three files: `qfoo.h`, `qfoo_p.h` and `qfoo.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

There is one called `QCircularBuffer`.

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qt3d-qcircularbuffer.html#details

`QCircularBuffer<T>` **is one of Qt's generic container classes**  (from documentation). So this class will fulfill all basic requirements of a container class.

Need to include **3dcore** library (`Qt3D` header).

Check your version of Qt can support it or not. I saw this in **Qt5.5**.

Comment: Quite the overhead to throw in another whole module for the sake of a single container. It should have been in QtCore...

Comment: @dtech I agree with you 100%

Comment: This class doesn't exist anymore. It was a transient API bug. You can certainly copy the sources into your own code, though.