# QCircularBuffer functionality without Qt3D

Tags: c++, qt

QCircularBuffer has exactly what I need, but adding Qt3D to our compiler bloats the build too much and I'm the only one who needs it so I'm looking for some help figuring out how to write this kind of functionality.

QRingbuffer also is an additional include that I cannot use. This needs to be accomplished without adding any new libraries.

I'm using c++ and I've seen a couple of ideas but they always include using QLists without limiting its size.

I need the QList to be limited to say 10 items, and once the tenth item has been added, the old items are overwritten and new items are pushed to the front.

So for example, if the array contains [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], and we continue adding elements, we'll see this:

[10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

[11,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

[12,11,10,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

[13,12,11,10,4,5,6,7,8,9]

etc

Here is what I'm doing currently:

```
if(list.size() > 10)
    list.push_front(newItem);
else
    list.push_back(newItem);
```

Obviously this isn't limiting the size of the list, and it's not overwriting the oldest items, only the first.

Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Qt have cyclic buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44188717/does-qt-have-cyclic-buffer)

Comment: It is possible to implement a circular buffer quite easily.  Do you want to use QList or could it be a stl library class such as an `<Array>`

Comment: Also wouldn't you want it to go circular such that after `[10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` it goes `[10,11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` not `[11,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

Comment: I would like to use QList

Comment: No, I would like for the new items to be first and then push the older ones to the right

Comment: As a starting point, you can have a look how Qt implemented it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them to push from the front with a max of ten then I would do something like this:

```
//somewhere higher up (maybe static) int curIndex = 0;
static const int LIST_SIZE = 10;
if(list.size() >= LIST_SIZE) //added an = here to make it 10 elements
{
    list.removeAt(curIndex);
    list.push_front(newItem);
    curIndex = (curIndex + 1) % LIST_SIZE;
}
else
    list.push_back(newItem);
```

*Note:* I do not have a compiler off hand to test this.

Comment: I forgot the type of circular you wanted.  This should work now.  Removes the index not wanted and adds from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, but it is only prepending the new element to index 0. So [1,2,3] becomes [4,2,3]  [5,2,3]  [6,2,3] etc.

Comment: Today is not my day.  Try now.  I never incremented the value.

Comment: That's basically doing what I need so thank you very much.  Only issue remaining is when it gets to 10, it removes that value from the list at the next update so [7,8,9]  [10,8,9], [11,8,9], [12,11,9] etc.

Comment: That means the `curIndex` is probably off by 1.  Step through it with the debugger and see where it erases the 10. You do have the `=` in the if statement right?